# Performance testing with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build a test which will fail upon slow / sluggish / jankiness performance of a web page or the elements within it.
By "slow" or "sluggish" i mean mostly the following:

- Very delayed response when scrolling down the page
- Delayed response when clicking an element

This sluggishness on particular page is happening when the system under test is scaled out.

One Idea i had to tackle this was to make a time out when explicitly waiting for some element to appear in the dome, but frankly i doubt this will answer my need, because i do see all elements in the dome, its just the page interaction is very slow both in FF and Chrome.

My Stack is Python3, Selenium WebDriver, Pytest

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Selenium is not designed for that. If you have URL's, just use Locust for performance tests. If you see the testing pyramid, e2e(Selenium) is about 2-5% of all tests.

Comment: If you already have the Selenium tests defined, then you could look into Taurus https://gettaurus.org/

Comment: Thanks, but how does Taurus has to do with the issue I described?